# Meta query stopped working

Tags: query-posts, meta-query, date

The following query stopped working all of a sudden and I can't figure out why.

```
<?php
$today = date("Y/m/j"); 
query_posts(array(
    'post_type' => array('events'),
    'meta_key' => 'event_date',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'event_date',
                'meta-value' => $value,
                'value' => $today,
                'compare' => '>=',
                'type' => 'CHAR'
                )
         )
   ));
?>
```

No plugins have been installed and no one thouched the code, and I have no php/javacript error on the page.

If I disable `value` in the meta_query, the posts show up fine, only there is no point of the query without it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should `'type' => 'CHAR'` actually be `'type' => 'DATE'`

the [Codex might help on the possible parameters you need here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Type_.26_Status_Parameters)

Comment: How come it worked with CHAR before?